# Apache ReadmeName for NGINX?

Tags: nginx

When using `autoindex on;` in NGINX, is it possible to show a readme.txt file right under the directory listing? Apache does it with the `ReadmeName` option.

Answer (score 1):

Use the slightly more advanced [Fancy Index](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/fancy_index/#fancyindex-footer) module instead of `autoindex`

```
fancyindex_footer path
```